# extract String values from Dictionary<String, AnyObject> in Swift

Tags: swift

I just want to extract some string values from a json response in Swift but I just can't find a simple way to do it.

```
var result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [ "name" : "Steve", "surname" : "Jobs"]

if let name = result["name"] {
    //Warning: Constant 'name' inferred to have 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected
}

if let name = result["name"] as String {
    //Error: (String, AnyObject) is not convertible to String
}
```

What is the correct way ?

cheers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*This answer was last revised for Swift 5.4 and Xcode 12.5.*

---

In Swift, `String` is a struct, not a class. You need to use `Any`, not `AnyObject`.

```swift
let result: [String: Any] = ["name" : "Steve", "surname" : "Jobs"]
```

Casting should be done optionally, using `as?` instead of `as`.

```swift
if let name = result["name"] as? String {
    // no error
}
```

Comment: `[KeyType: ValueType]` does not work (use of undeclared type "KeyType"). I use Xcode beta 4.

Comment: Uhm... That was a placeholder. In your case you should use `[String: Any]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) which is a better way to deal with JSON data in Swift

```
var result: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = [ "name" : "Steve", "surname" : "Jobs"]
let json = SwiftJSON.JSON(object: result)

if let name = json["name"].string {
    //do what you want
} else {
    //print the error message if you like
    println(json["name"])
}
```